# Change name of scaffold routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Is there a way to change the name of the routes that my scaffold created? I made a scaffold for Cars. Currently I have `resources :cars` in my routes. How can I change the routes such that my url shows http://localhost:3000/transportation instead of http://localhost:3000/cars? I do not need to change the name of the entity in my schema, all I want to change are the routes associated with it. How can I go about this?

Is there no other way to achieve this but to do a get for each? Ex:

```
get '/transportation', to: 'cars#index', as: 'cars_index'
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: @Зелёный I edited my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the new route after the `resources` created by your scaffold to respond to your cars controller and index action, or any other other, depending on what you want to achieve.

```
resources :cars
get 'transportation', to: 'cars#index'
```

If you want to apply it for all your routes on the car scaffold, then you can pass a path option:

```
resources :cars, path: 'transportations'
```

This way the routes pointing to car won't be available and will be replaced for transportations.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine resource routes with custom URLs by passing a string of your choice along with `:path` option along with its route definition in `routes.rb`

```
resources :cars, :path => "transportation"
```

With this route definition, access to `cars` resources in your app will be routed to these URLs

```
     cars GET      /transportation(.:format)                    cars#index
          POST     /transportation(.:format)                    cars#create
  new_car GET      /transportation/new(.:format)                cars#new
 edit_car GET      /transportation/:id/edit(.:format)           cars#edit
      car GET      /transportation/:id(.:format)                cars#show
          PATCH    /transportation/:id(.:format)                cars#update
          PUT      /transportation/:id(.:format)                cars#update
          DELETE   /transportation/:id(.:format)                cars#destroy
```